# Is the information displayed on my landing page too much?

Tags: landing-page, cta

I've launched the website https://XXXXX.com/ a month ago and have now added a landing page to the website to draw more visitors. The landing page consists of four pictures that display different features of the website along with text that describes each feature. At the bottom is a CTA phrase that prompts the visitor to join the community by registering now.

My question is about the text next to each picture. Is the text too long for a landing page or is it ok? I've hilighted the important parts in each column of text in order to capture the visitors attention and to motivate them to read the rest of the text as well. I would also like to know your opinions about the landing page overall and if their are any ways in which it can be improved. You can visit https://XXXXXX.com/ to see it.

Answer (score 3):

The site does not [sizzle](https://millyuns.com/sizzle/).

[image: before]

(Ignoring the header with the giant banner ad...)

The site describes what the user can do—that's important, but what's missing is the benefit. Feature the benefit—sell the sizzle.

Also, be mindful what is [above the fold](https://www.mindspun.com/blog/above-the-fold/). In this case there is only one of the functions of the site.

Be sure to give the user the big picture view right up front, without having to scroll, scan, and recall.

For example:

[image: after]

At the very top is a summary description of the nature of the site, a journal. Followed by graphic and text introductions to the primary functionality of the site...

*...framed as benefits.*

Not shown, but each function block links to it's corresponding section below.

Regarding each longer description of each function, also be sure to feature, and highlight, the *benefits* of the functions.

Finally, the call to action (CTA):

```
Join the Community and Register Now!
```

There is a benefit there: "Join the Community". The desired action is clear: "Register" and it's timely: "Now!". What is the most fulfilling benefit? Is it the community? Is it the harvest? Is it the mastery of a craft? Is it...

Answer (score 1):

It is a lot of text. Two questions that might help you, to judge whether you have the right amount of text are:

1. Is all of this really the information, the user needs to have on hand at this point of the journey?
2. Is the text compressed to a minimum of length by full span of information?
   If you can confirm both questions with a yes, you probably have the right amount of text. If it still feels like a lot, it might help to get some users, try some tasks in the flow and question whether they had all the information they wished for, or whether the text was read or helpful.

You also mentioned that you highlighted certain words in the text to draw the users attention. I assume you meant the bold text within the copytext. You might want to hightlight less words in the text and use a more prominent appraoch to highlight them, as they not really stuck out to me.

Plus, if you limited the text to less words, you might not need to highlight text within the text.